# NextJS server components are running in the client side too

Tags: javascript, next.js, material-ui

I am tring to use Material UI `v5.11.16` with nextjs `v13.3.0` and setup my nextjs project as the official documentation suggests [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/HEAD/examples/material-next-ts) and I am able to use Material UI components without writing `"use client"` at the top of my files.

The issue is that I tried to check if a component is server component or not. I put a `console.log("type of window: ", typeof window)` to see if `typeof window` is `undefined` it is server component, or if that is an object it is a client component.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function Home() {
  console.log("this typeof window: ", typeof window)
  
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
      <Typography>
      </Typography>
      <Box
        sx={{
          my: 4,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h1" gutterBottom>
          Material UI - Next.js example in TypeScript
        </Typography>
        <Button
          variant="outlined"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("clicked!");
          }}
        >
          TESTing Button
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

I realized that the `console.log` is executing on both server side and client side, it logs `the typeof window:  undefined` in the server log and prints `the typeof window:  object` in browsers console. Why it is running on both sides?

I tried putting `use client` at the top of the file, again that was logged in the server too. what is really happening here ?
*Is it safe to put tokens or I mean do server things in these components ?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to understand that when using Next.js, SSR is utilized by default. This means that components are initially rendered on the server and then sent to the client. On the client side, React components will "hydrate" or re-render with any additional changes or interactivity. This is the reason why you see logs for the same component on both the server side and the client side.

The' typeof window' check you performed is a common method to determine if your code is running on the server or client side. However, it does not prevent your code from being executed on the server-side. It just gives you information about the current environment.

I hope this helps

Comment: So is it safe to do server things in these components ?

Comment: Yes, Would you like to take a look at the features provided by Next.js: `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, and `getInitialProps`? Better touch the server side data here!